# Zip drive eject "tool"

Tags: repair, storage, cd-rom

So I am trying to manually eject a Zip disk from a Zip drive.  This is not a OEM Zip drive, but one made specifically for a Pentium laptop.  I went to the dollar store and bought a pack of paper clips, as I probably havent had or seen a paperclip in years.  Unfortunately, the paperclip would just bend under the pressure of trying to push in the eject mechanism.  It could just be the dollar store paperclips are made out of inferior metal than "quality" paperclips.  However, I dont want to go shopping for paperclips.  Even if I find one that works, I will more than likely lose it (or the entire pack) and not be able to find one when I need it again.  I have several sets of micro-screwdrivers, but while a few are thin enough, they arent long enough to reach the eject mechanism.

So my questions is, is there a tool out there that is thin enough, long enough, and strong enough for ejecting Zip disks (and CDs, etc)?  I would like *something* that is larger than a paperclip - something I can put in a toolbox and not lose.  Any ideas?

Edit:  Surprisingly, there are no "zip-drive" or "tool" tags

Comment: I think this is more about finding a modern long thin durable metal bar than it's use on retrocomputing. That said, many CD drives were sold with a fancy metal tool to open them instead of using paperclips.

Comment: Your local hardware store likely has spring steel wire in various diameters and lengths.

Comment: @Justme This seems on-topic for me: It's not just about finding a long thin durable metal bar, but specifically finding a tool that is the right size, length, and strength to eject a Zip drive.

Comment: Paperclips - ah the old tool of choice. For Zip drive eject, CD/DVD (still today!) eject and for serial port ("real" serial ports - e.g., RS232 and similar, not this newfangled USB stuff) troubleshooting. For serial ports doesn't matter much, but for eject, there are two (maybe more, but 2 mainly) sizes of paperclips - regular and jumbo. You might well need jumbo for this, though I finally tossed my last Zip drives a few months ago, so can't say for sure.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Your point about the different sizes of paperclips is good.  May I please add that to my answer?

Comment: @WayneConrad **Absolutely.** Your answer (a) is pretty good anyway and (b) I am contemplating going on official Stack Exchange/Overflow strike, which is why I did not make my own answer.

Comment: I think I'd go on this with @Justme. Finding a generic metal pin is really not much RC.SE related. Even more when this is a custom drive (enclosure) which means that the hole may have a complete different diameter than regular ZIP drives. Simply measuring that diameter and getting a steel wire that size will be the way to go.

Comment: Got any "sim tray tools" that might be floating in a junk draw? They are pretty sturdy, although might not be long enough depending on the Zip.

Comment: @Coxy Sim card ejector tool is definitely not long enough

Comment: how about an embroidery needle? do you know someone who may have one lying around? they are lang enough and sturdy

Comment: @Keltari How long do you think you need? This one [no affiliation, searched for "extra long"] is half an inch: https://www.amazon.com/PortPlugs-Earphone-Plug-Set-Smartphones/dp/B01LP5PIUU

Comment: I have an old key ring which I partially uncoiled for this purpose.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly the quality of the dollar store paperclip.  If you buy a box of paperclips from a stationary store, you are more likely to get paperclips made from thicker and stronger metal that will work.

From [this comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/zip-drive-eject-tool#comment96058_27171):

> there are two (maybe more, but 2 mainly) sizes of paperclips - regular and jumbo. You might well need jumbo for this. - @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact

To keep from losing your chosen paperclip, and to make it easy to find in your toolbox, use cord or wire to attach it to something such as a small board or piece of cardboard.  You can label the board or cardboard if desired.

Comment: Also, get larger than the standard paperclip size. They are made with thicker metal.

Comment: You won't buy a single paperclip unless it's one of those giant ones. Instead of trying to tether one paperclip, put the pack in a drawer. If you have a toolbox, throw in a few paperclips.

Comment: @WeatherVane I suggested buying a box of paperclips, not a single one (as you note, you can't generally buy single paperclips).  A small box of paperclips is inexpensive.

Comment: I keep a "good" paperclip and two bandaids in my wallet at all times.

Comment: @Criggie - no P38 can opener? - If memory serves me right, jumbos are too big.

Comment: @Mazura for some reason, my old leatherman doesn't have paperclip or bandaid storage.  It does have a can-opener though.

Answer (score 14):

A very thin Allen key. I've got a .05" one in my toolkit which was originally there for aligning Shugart floppy discs and by now is used almost entirely for misbehaving DVD drives etc.

I'd caution against sewing needles, thin twist drills and so on since they're often tempered "hard" rather than "tough" and having one break can be unpleasant.

Off-topic observation: the blue Zip drives are identical in colour to one model of SGI computer. I don't know whether this was a coincidence, or was due to a large order being cancelled when they were found to have reliability problems.

Somewhat later observation: I might be wrong here, but I have a vague recollection that at least some of the Zip drives we had didn't have an eject hole but instead had a very small wire loop at the front which needed to be pulled with a spring hook or a pair of needle-nose pliers. I can't find this on any photos, so it might be specific to the fairly early SCSI-connected drives we were using.

Comment: Do you mean the [SGI O2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Graphics#/media/File:SGI_O2_front.jpg)? A lot of the other SGI models were closer to mauve/purple, apart from the [540](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_Graphics#/media/File:Sgi-540_01.jpg) (the Octane was more of a Teal). However the [IOmega ZIP 650](https://i0.wp.com/applerescueofdenver.com/wp-content/uploads/zipcd650-6.jpg) looks purple.

Comment: Can't remember TBH, but I had one and out of curiosity slipped a standard (SCSI?) Zip drive (i.e. not a CD) into the blanked 3.5" position and any colour mismatch was undetectable. One thing I didn't do was check the colour against a RAL swatch (a bit like Pantone, but specifically for plastics) since if it had turned out to be non-standard it would have been significant indication of a (failed) attempt at collaboration.

Comment: 0.05" isn't "very thin" for a hex key, or at least not if you've used 0.7mm! but that or a 1mm should be good here

Comment: I assure you that I've used /much/ smaller tools than that. However apart from its provenance the interesting thing about this particular tool is its length, which is about 7" rather than the inch or so you'd expect for something that thin.

Comment: Sewing needles, no.  But *knitting* needles might work, if you get a small enough gauge.  Possibly crochet needles as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that knitting needles ("knitting pins" to some I believe) exist that thin. Crochet hooks definitely go down to at least 0.5mm but looking at my repair kit tend to be tapered, also I don't know how tough they are since they're not intended to handle more than a single thread at a time.

Comment: Apparently knitting needles go down to at least 1mm, which *might* be small enough?  I think I've seen them that size in my mom's knitting kit.  They are tapered, but so are sewing needles - knitting needles at least don't come to a sharp point, which could be brittle.  Crochet hooks I'd avoid, mainly because of the *hook*, and the possibility of it getting stuck in there.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Allowing that 0.05" is 25.4/20 mm which is >1mm, I agree with ChrisH that "a 1mm should be good here". My understanding is that in the case of both a crochet hook and a knitting needle the size is that of the loop(s) being manipulated, so while a knitting needle comes to a point it will not go larger than the nominal size but a crochet hook has the hook of nominal size at the tip with a larger diameter backing it up.

Answer (score 5):

Sewing needles are made of harder steel than paperclips.

Buy a pack of assorted sizes, ideally with small eyes. Stab the largest size that fits into a cork (along the axis of a wine cork would work well) or large eraser to use as a handle, so you're not inserting the sharp end into the drive.  There's no need to push on it like you're pushing  a pin into a board, just grip it in your hand in case you push far too hard and manage to get a long needle right through and out the other side.

For big holes, you can also use the handle part of a foldback binder clip, though you may need to straighten it with pliers.  I *think* I did that when I had a zip drive, but possibly using a rather small clip

Comment: This one sounds honestly quite dangerous. You're going to push the needle right through your cork/rubber "handle", sooner or later, probably sooner. And that's going to be a trip straight to hospital.

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic how often do you expect to use it?  And hospital for a little prick in the finger?  Although I was envisaging gripping the cork, not pressing against the end (hence "handle"; I would have said you were using the cork as a pin head if you're pressing against the opposite end), so I need to edit that in

Comment: This is not dangerous. Most of the wine and beer corks that I have seen are about the length of a sewing needle, so at the very least you’d know before it pokes through. However you’d probably know well before that because the needle would no longer travel enough to reset the pin first. As for the potential consequences, just be sure to invite all the fairy godmothers to your kids baptism and you’re good.

Comment: One could also remove or blunt the sharp tip of the needle.  I don't know if diagonal cutters would go through the hardened steel of a sewing needle, but if not, then I'd think that a file would do it.

Comment: @WayneConrad a few strokes of a file will blunt a needle nicely, that's true.  Then you could use it either way round

Comment: @WayneConrad Diagonal cutters intended for copper would definitely be damaged. Ones with a "piano wire" rating *might* not be damaged. The cut pieces with sharp pointy ends are likely to try to fly apart at high speed.

Comment: @AndrewMorton's right. If I really had to cut a needle I'd use my cutters for bike cables, or a Dremel mini grinder

Answer (score 3):

SIM card eject tool. You can get quite nice ones with a cover to keep the tip from being damaged.

Comment: As noted in [this comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/zip-drive-eject-tool#comment96127_27171), it probably isn't long enough

Comment: @Greenonline I don't remember the zip drive eject being _that_ long, but it was a long time ago. I asked for some clarification about how long the OP thinks they need for this.

Answer (score 3):

While I bought it as a sim removal tool, there's watch band removal tools - which are essentially a pin on a knurled handle. I got one off aliexpress years ago

[image]

and it looks like this. You can get the pin with different diameters and they're a lot sturdier than 'regular' sim card tools or paperclips

The pokey bit is about 1.5cm and the handle is about 4cm on mine.

Comment: How long are the tips? It would be useful to state that in the answer. As noted in [this comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27171/zip-drive-eject-tool#comment96127_27171), they *might* not be long enough. That said, they *do* look very nice.

Comment: Updated with that information. And yeah, they are very nice, and useful for a whole bunch of other things too :D

Answer (score 1):

Sewing awl handle, plus potentially sewing awl needle. I don't know the technical name for the type of fastener, but you put the needle in and spin to tighten down like a drill chuck, so you could change out the needle for a quality paperclip or something. The needles that come with it will are possibly OK for this task since sewing awls are usually used for leather or other tough material where you may need to put a lot of force to get the needle through the material, but you might want to file the end otherwise the point can damage the plastic pin that you push to release the drive. Also, as a bonus, the needle might come with a specified gauge so you can decide if a given needle will fit before you purchase. Just watch out for ones where the needle is tapered since it will probably not fit far enough in.

Answer (score 0):

1mm drill bit. Just be careful not to snap it.

Answer (score 0):

The tool is the "CD drive ejector pin", the trouble is that you can hardly find it today. It came routinely with better quality drives back then, I still have one in my desk tray, although I haven't used it in ages, of course. Much sturdier than a paperclip, actually, it would require quite some force to bend it.

Having said that, there are three contemporary tools, all easily and readily available, that can do the same.

1. **Desoldering needle.** Just Google it, you'll get ample results. Even a full set is very cheap, but you only need one that fits. Comes with a nice, colored handle, just like a real tool. :-)
2. A simple and ubiquitous **hypodermic needle.** Just grind off the point to make it blunt (no need for special tools, you can remove the sharp point even with sandpaper and a little bit of elbow grease).
3. **Sewing machine needle** (not sewing needle but sewing machine, specifically, those have a thicker stem that makes it much easier to handle in this case). Again, grind off the sharp point.

Actually, either of the first two would be the best. If you want the handle, just buy a cheap desoldering needle set. If you want a quick but sturdy workaround, get a hypodermic in the nearest pharmacy. The sewing machine one *might* be brittle, as other have noted, I never really tried. But the first two are hollow, rather strong for their size, stainless steel and would probably outlast any intended use.

Comment: You can get blunt ended needles, although maybe not from a high street pharmacy.